# VerifyEmailError not defined after installing verify_email library (Python 3.11.5)

Tags: python, error-handling, email-validation

I am using Python 3.11.5 and installed the verify_email library to validate email addresses. However, when I attempt to catch the VerifyEmailError exception using a try-except block, I receive the following error:

```
except verify_email.VerifyEmailError as e:
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'verify_email' has no attribute 'VerifyEmailError'
```

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling the verify_email library multiple times, but the issue persists.

Comment: I don't see that error class mentioned anywhere in the library's documentation. What makes you think it should exist?

Comment: I appear to have misread something. sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `verify-email` does not throw an exception if a verification failed. Thus there is not exception you can import.

```py
from verify_email import verify_email

print(verify_email(some_wrong_email)) # => False
print(verify_email(some_right_email)) # => True
```

You can use that to check if an email is correct and do something if it is or isn't

```py
from verify_email import verify_email

if verify_email(some_email):
    # Do something with correct email
else:
    # Do something with wrong email
```